# Glyphs from font not displayed

Tags: symbols, unicode, warnings

I am trying to get Xelatex printing these glyphs from the font I'm using (it's Garamond Premier Pro):

```
▼ ◺ ◹
```

I tried both by copying and pasting them in my document and by their UTF code with:

```
\char "25BC \char "25FA \char "25F9
```

I get a warning:

> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

Strangely enough the following:

```
◆ \char "25C6
```

works both by copy/paste and by `\char` command.

Any clue?
Thank you,
A

*EDIT*

Here is a minimal code which shows the problem (actually I don't get any warning with this, but still the glyphs are not displayed).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, twoside]{article}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures={Common}, Numbers={OldStyle}]{Garamond Premier Pro}

\usepackage{xunicode}


\begin{document}
Glyphs testing. The following ones don't get displayed:

▼ ◺ ◹ 
\char "25BC  \char "25FA  \char "25F9


This one works:

◆ \char "25C6 

\end{document}
```

At the end of the file `glyphstesting.log` I found errors: these symbols actually ARE there in the Garamond Premier Pro character map under the common group.

> Missing character: There is no ▼ in font Garamond Premier Pro/OT:script=latn;la
>   nguage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+liga;+onum;!
>
> Missing character: There is no ◺ in font Garamond Premier Pro/OT:script=latn;la
>   nguage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+liga;+onum;!
>
> Missing character: There is no ◹ in font Garamond Premier Pro/OT:script=latn;la
>   nguage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+liga;+onum;!
>
> Missing character: There is no ▼ in font Garamond Premier Pro/OT:script=latn;la
>   nguage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+liga;+onum;!
>
> Missing character: There is no ◺ in font Garamond Premier Pro/OT:script=latn;la
>   nguage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+liga;+onum;!
>
> Missing character: There is no ◹ in font Garamond Premier Pro/OT:script=latn;la
>   nguage=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;+liga;+onum;!

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with the existence of glyphs in a font.

Comment: The warning is telling you that some font was not found so LaTeX substituted an alternative e.g. it couldn't find small-caps so used upright, or it couldn't find Palatino upright in bold extended so substituted Computer Modern Roman or whatever. Without seeing (1) your code and/or (2) more of the log, all we can do is guess. We don't even know whether LaTeX found the font you requested at all or not.

Comment: Edited my question with a minimal code representing the issue.

Comment: The version of Garamond Premier Pro I have, doesn't have those glyphs. Are you sure you don't have two versions of the font installed, and the one picked up by xelatex is the wrong one?

Comment: Maybe the character map displays the glyphs even when not included in the font? How do I know if a font has a particular glyph?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions: I tried setting the DejaVu font and the glyphs now are displayed.